# Formation of Runge-Kutta method

Tags: numerical-methods

> A Runge-Kutta method for numerically solving the initial value ordinary value differential equation $y'(x)=f(x,y)$ ; $y(x_0)=y_0$ is given by ( for $h$ small )$$y(x+h)=y(x)+w_1F_1(x,y)+w_2F_2(x,y)$$ $$F_2(x,y)=hf(x,y)$$ $$F_2(x,y)=hf(x+\alpha h,y+\beta F_1).$$ The objective is to determine the constants $w_1 , w_2,\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that the above formula is accurate to order $2$. **Which of the following are correct sets of values for these constants ?**

(A) $ w_1=w_2=\frac{1}{2}, \alpha=\beta=1$.

(B) $w_1=2 , w_2=1,\alpha =\frac{1}{2}, \beta=\frac{1}{2}$.

(C) $w_1=\frac{1}{3} , w_2=\frac{2}{3},\alpha =\frac{3}{4}, \beta=\frac{3}{4}$.

(D) $w_1=\frac{3}{4} , w_2=\frac{1}{4},\alpha =2, \beta=2$.

**Approach :**

Putting the values of option (A) in the given formula , I got the formula as 2nd order R-K method. But I can't figure out for the other options. Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remember the first consistency conditions which state that $α=β$ and $w_1+w_2=1$ to get at least an order 1 method.

---

If you remember your Taylor series, then you know that the exact solution satisfies
$$
y(x+h)=y(x)+hf(x,y)+\frac12h^2(f_x+f_yf)+O(h^3)
$$
and in the RK method
$$
y_+=y+hf(x,y)+w_2αh^2(f_x+f_yf)+O(h^3)
$$
giving the only extra condition $w_2α=\frac12$.